# Merge multiple CSV files using Pandas to create final CSV file with dynamic header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, merge

I have 4 [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) files with `\t` or `tab` as delimiter.

```
alok@alok-HP-Laptop-14s-cr1:~/tmp/krati$ for file in sample*.csv; do echo $file; cat $file; echo ; done
sample1.csv
ProbeID p_code  intensities
B1_1_3  6170    2
B2_1_3  6170    2.2
B3_1_4  6170    2.3
12345   6170    2.4
1234567 6170    2.5

sample2.csv
ProbeID p_code  intensities
B1_1_3  5320    3
B2_1_3  5320    3.2
B3_1_4  5320    3.3
12345   5320    3.4
1234567 5320    3.5

sample3.csv
ProbeID p_code  intensities
B1_1_3  1234    4
B2_1_3  1234    4.2
B3_1_4  1234    4.3
12345   1234    4.4
1234567 1234    4.5

sample4.csv
ProbeID p_code  intensities
B1_1_3  3120    5
B2_1_3  3120    5.2
B3_1_4  3120    5.3
12345   3120    5.4
1234567 3120    5.5
```

All 4 files have same headers.

`ProbeID` is same across all files, order is also same. Each file have same `p_code` across single CSV file.

I have to merge all these CSV files into one in this format.

```
alok@alok-HP-Laptop-14s-cr1:~/tmp/krati$ cat output1.csv 
ProbeID 6170    5320    1234    3120
B1_1_3  2       3       4       5
B2_1_3  2.2     3.2     4.2     5.2
B3_1_4  2.3     3.3     4.3     5.3
12345   2.4     3.4     4.4     5.4
1234567 2.5     3.5     4.5     5.5
```

In this output file columns are dynamic based on `p_code` value.

I can do this easily in [Python](https://www.python.org/) using dictionary. How can I produce such output using [Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_(software))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can achieve this using [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
import os
import pandas as pd

df = pd.concat(
    [pd.read_csv(f, sep="\t") for f in os.listdir() if f.endswith(".csv") and f.startswith("sample")], 
    ignore_index=True
)

df = df.pivot_table(index="ProbeID", columns="p_code", values="intensities", aggfunc="sum")
print(df)
```

Comment: It works on my laptop, hard to debug like this. Can you print `df` after the line with `pd.concat` and see if you have one dataframe with the three columns: `ProbeID, p_code, intensities`

Comment: Now it's confusing, please be concise, is it `intensities` or `tintensities`? It;s not about python or linux, the name of column is just wrong.

Comment: That's an important detail you did not provide, your seperator is a tab. See edit in `pd.read_csv`

Comment: sorry I have added that detail in question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221227/discussion-between-erfan-and-alok-singh-mahor).